# Как оформить специальный блок текста?

Tags: latex

Хочу расставить в документе специальные блоки типа "Замечание", "Предупреждение", подсказка и т.д. Приблизительно вот такого вида:

[image: Пример специального блока "Note"]

После того, как перерыл кучу литературы и форумов, единственное, что нашёл - использование пакета awesomebox:

```
\usepackage{awesomebox}
. . . 
\notebox{Для получения дополнительной информации о настройке подключения к удаленному интерфейсу см. Руководств...}
```

И здесь возникли две проблемы:

1. Пакет awesomebox использует пакет fontawesome5, а он расположен внутри гиганского пакета (с точки зрения инсталлятора Ubuntu) texlive-fonts-extra
2. Эффект от его использования оказался хотя и похож на желаемое, но не совсем:

[image: Применение awesomebox]

И причём тут буква "J" ?! Её можно заменить на что-то более вменяемое? Или, может быть есть какой-то более простой путь?

Comment: [см.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16223/79376) (и связанные с ним вопросы)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Посмотрел и даже проверил... Круто!!!
Напишите в "ответ" - я Вам галку поставлю. :-)

Comment: у вышеприведённой ссылки есть связанные вопросы. а там ещё связанные. и в них упоминаются разные варианты создания блоков. да и просто [поиском](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=image+paragraph) ещё множество [способов](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=icon+paragraph) находится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для выделения блоков текста с какими-то объектами слева можно использовать разные способы. Можно использовать два стоящих рядом `parbox`-а, можно все целиком отрисовывать в каком-то графическом пакете (типа `tikz/pgf`), наверное, можно даже использовать таблицу и в ее ячейки сложить нужные метку и текст. Я попытался решить задачу тремя разными способами (с переменным успехом):

1. через штатные средства LaTeX `parbox`-ы с окружением `picture` (получилось не очень);
2. используя смесь из команд `tikz` и какого-то бокса (`\fcolorbox`);
3. используя `tikz` и пакет `tcolorbox`.

Все варианты оформлены в виде макросов, первым параметром нужно указывать метку (символ), вторым параметром идет текст с сообщением. Цвета, размеры шрифтов/размеры полей можно в небольших пределах варьировать. Где зависело от меня, я явно задавал размер поля для метки, а размер поля для текста вычислялся из полной ширины рабочего поля и этого поля для метки (использовал пакет `calc`).

**Первый вариант.** Хотелось сделать так, чтобы не нужны были внешние зависимости.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%  #1 - метка (символ, например, ! ? i)
%  #2 - текст
\newcommand{\boxA}[2]{%
    \medskip
    \noindent
    \color{gray!30!white}
    \fcolorbox{blue!30!white}{yellow!20!white}{%
    \color{black}
    \parbox[t][1.4cm]{1.4cm}{
        \begin{center}
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
            \begin{picture}(14,14)
               \put(7.5,7.5){\color{red!70!black}\scalebox{2.5}{\circle*{14}}}%
               \put(5,5){\color{white}\scalebox{3}{\texttt{#1}}}
            \end{picture}
        \end{center}
    }%
    \hspace{4mm}
    \parbox[t]{{\textwidth-2.2cm}}{#2}%
    }
    \color{black}
    \par
    \medskip
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

%\boxA{i}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
\boxA{!}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
%\boxA{\textsf{?}}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{document}
```

В примере закомментированы два вызова макроса, чтобы на картинке меньше места занимать. В домашних условиях комментарии можно снять.

По факту, во внешних зависимостях у меня оказался все тот же пакет `tikz` из-за команды масштабирования `\scalebox`. Но если я правильно помню, эта команда реализована в разных пакетах (есть в `graphicx`) и можно брать его (а еще `tikz` неявно подгружает пакет `xcolor`, поэтому его тогда тоже надо будет добавить). Данная команда (`\scalebox`) понадобилась из тех соображений, что в окружении `picture` есть фигура типа "круг" (с заливкой) только с максимальным размером 14mm. И этого размера не хватает (для моего вкуса). И с этим способом есть пара неприятных моментов: 1) *я не знаю как автоматически разместить точно в центр круга нужный символ, поэтому я его положение подгонял руками - если достаточно сильно изменить размер или начертание шрифта для символа, то надо будет подбирать координаты (в команде `\put`);* 2) *по какой-то непонятной мне причине при размещении в одной строке двух парбоксов, в одном из которых текст, а в другом - только графика, парбоксам сносит крышу и они не хотят выравниваться по верхнему краю.* Если кто-то подскажет, как с этими проблемами бороться, то тогда можно считать рабочим и этот вариант. А так, я его сделал исключительно для пробы сил.

И еще, на всякий случай напишу - в макросе иногда в конце строки стоит символ комментария - он там *нужен*, он подавляет лишние пробелы.

Результат получился какой-то такой:

[image: Результат работы первого макроса]

**Второй вариант.** Можно было все честно разместить на одном рисунке и вообще не париться, но мы простых путей не ищем, поэтому `\fcolorbox` для фона и рамки остался от первого варианта :-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%  #1 - метка (символ, например, ! ? i)
%  #2 - текст
\newcommand{\boxB}[2]{%
    \medskip
    \noindent
    \color{gray!30!white}%
    \fcolorbox{blue!30!white}{yellow!20!white}{%
    \color{black}%
    \hspace{1mm}
        \tikz[terminal/.style={
         circle,minimum size=5mm,very thick,draw=red!50,top color=white,bottom color=red!20,font=\ttfamily
%         ball color=red,circle,text=white, minimum size=5mm, font=\ttfamily
        }]
        {
            \node (Sign) at (0,0) [anchor=north west, terminal]{\scalebox{2}{#1}};
            \node (text) at (1,0.2) [anchor=north west, rectangle, text width = {\textwidth-2cm}, align=justify]{{#2}};
        }
    }
    \color{black}
    \medskip
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

%\boxB{i}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}
\boxB{!}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
%\boxB{?}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{document}
```

Здесь все гораздо проще (с расположением полей), единственное, я так и не решил, какое оформление метки лучше смотрится. Поэтому оставил два стиля (`terminal/.style={ ...`) - можно одну строку закомментировать, а другую раскомементировать и посмотреть на другое оформление. И здесь получилось сделать так, чтобы метка и текст были выровнены по верхнему краю.

[image: Второй вариант]

А вот так выглядит альтернативное оформление:

[image: Альтернативный второй вариант]

Собственно, в `tikz` можно рисовать всякие сложные объекты, это просто примеры, чтобы было быстрее. Все цвета можно подстраивать под свои пожелания. Здесь шрифт метки можно спокойно менять, `tikz` справится с центрированием.

**Ну и третий вариант.** Я честно стащил стиль оформления из книжки официальной документации пакета `tcolorbox`, разве только слегка "доработал напильником": там был рассмотрен более сложный случай, я просто удалил все лишнее и добавил буковку на шарик.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

%  #1 - метка (символ, например, ! ? i)
%  #2 - текст
\newcommand{\boxC}[2]{%
    \medskip
    \noindent
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,sharp corners,
        boxrule=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=1mm,right=1mm,
        leftrule=2cm,colupper=blue!25!black,
        frame style={pattern=crosshatch dots light steel blue},overlay={%
            \begin{tcbclipframe}
                {\coordinate (X) at ([xshift=10mm]frame.west);}
                \fill[shading=ball,ball color=red!50!white,opacity=0.9] (X) circle (6mm);
                \draw (X) node[color=white,font=\ttfamily\Huge]{#1};
        \end{tcbclipframe}}]
        #2
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \medskip
}



\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-5]

%\boxC{i}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
\boxC{!}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
%\boxC{?}{\lipsum[2][1-6]}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{document}
```

Здесь получился самый заковыристый вариант по внешнему оформлению. Правда метка располагается по центру блока (по вертикали) и я не стал уже бороться за то, чтоб ее подтянуть к верхнему краю.

Должно получиться что-то такое:

[image: Третий вариант оформления]

Здесь я задавал только размер левого поля (для метки), а поле для текста оно считает само.

Во всех вариантах вместо метки (левой) можно подгружать какой-нибудь интересный рисунок. Главное задать ему правильный размер (чтоб вписалось в размеры) и потом компилировать правильным способом (если `pdf` или растровые рисунки, то собирать только через `pdflatex`, а векторные `eps` - через `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`).

Вот как-то так.

Comment: Очень обстоятельный ответ! Я бы сказал, что тянет на статью в каком-нибудь ресурсе для начинающих докписов. «Любая достаточно развитая технология неотличима от магии» - третий закон Кларка :-) 

Попробовал все три варианта - всё работает.  Сейчас буду решать - какой красивее :-)

Comment: @Sergey, спасибо! Но в первом варианте я не знаю как правильно бороться с указанными косяками, поэтому на качественную статью не пойдет :-). Но если первый вариант делать не как универсальный макрос, а в каждом конкретном случае подгонять "костылями", то вроде можно и его использовать.

Comment: А с кириллицей не работает :-(  Я заменил   \usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc} на \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} (я под Linux работаю) добавил \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} но это не помогло.

Comment: @Sergey, Это странно, я проверил - под Win10 в TeXLive 2020 (это тот же дистрибутив латеха, что и в линух) с UTF-8 все (я только второй вариант проверял) работает с кириллицей вместо символа метки. Чуть позже перегружусь в бубунту и еще там посмотрю. На всякий случай - проверьте, не закрался ли в Ваш файл BOM - если я правильно помню, латех его не любит.

Comment: Я разобрался в причине такого поведения. Наверное, сам виноват! Дело в том, что когда я скопипастил Ваши примеры, они были сохранены на диске в кодировке cp1251. И Ваши кирилические комменты я не видел. Тогда я исправил комменты, заменил cp1251 на utf8 и вставил внутрь макроса кириллицу.  Ничего не вышло! Эта зараза (под названием TexStudio) каким-то образом запомнила, что данный файл в кодировке cp1251 и когда я вставил туда текст на кириллице (уже в utf8), начала ругаться.  Кроче, я выполнил конвертацию кодировки и все Ваши примеры заработали с кириллицей.

Answer (score 2):

По совету  aleksandr barakin воспользовался пакетом bclogo.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}{Nice bclogo example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{bclogo}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur = blue!30,couleurBord=red!50,logo=\bcoutil]{Nice 
bclogo example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{bclogo}

\begin{bclogo}[arrondi=0.1,epBarre=0,couleur = 
green!30,couleurBord=orange!50,logo=\bcfeutricolore]{Nice bclogo example}
\lipsum[3]
\end{bclogo}
\end{document}
```

Результаты меня вполне устроили:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]