# LaTeX - как выделять блоки?

Tags: latex

В технической документации, как правило, есть параграфы, которые выделяются специальным образом. Например:

- Предупреждение
- Обратить внимание
- Опасно

Не могу найти подходящего инструмента в LaTex - подскажите!

Comment: Определите «специальные образы».  Имеется в виду цвет шрифта, цвет фона, отступы?

Comment: Приведите пример, как Вы хотите это оформить и тогда ответы будут конкретнее. А так, есть `\parbox`, есть окружение `minipage`, есть с десяток разных типов пробелов (горизонтальных/вертикальных), есть пакет [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) для удобной работы с цветом. И есть пакет [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), которого более чем достаточно для всяких боксов. Но даже если этого не достаточно - еще есть тайное оружие посвященных - пакеты [`pgf/tikz`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: @Vladimir "Приведите пример, как Вы хотите это оформить" - ну вот тут, к примеру, очень красиво оформлены блоки кода: http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html

Но я имел в виду нечто попроще - там где блок текста сдвинут вправо, а на левой стороне красный кружок с буквой "i" - Информация, вопросительным и восклицательным знаком и т.д.

Comment: По ссылке - это похоже на пакет `listings` (там все настраивается, но не уверен про рисунки на полях) - что касается кусков кода. А дальше в тексте - может и есть другой спец.  пакет (но можно сделать как я дальше описал). А то что Вы написали делается с помощью пары `\parbox`-ов и картинки (можно тем же `tikz`-ом прямо в документе). Т.е. это настолько просто, что нет смысла для такого делать что-то особенное (команды или пакеты).

Comment: @Sergey, если хотите, я ближе к вечеру (сейчас немного занят) могу сделать пример макросов для таких выделений. Если никто раньше не сделает.

Comment: @Vladimir "могу сделать пример макросов для таких выделений." - буду Вам очень благодарен!

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/959410/178576)?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin "дубликат ?" - фактически, да. bclogo у меня так и не заработал сегодня. Говорит, что конфликтует по фонтам с каки-то другим пакетом. Я толком не смог разобраться.

Мне бы что попроще...

Comment: *конфликтует по фонтам с каки-то другим пакетом* — может быть об этом и надо задавать вопрос вместо дубликата?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как оформить специальный блок текста?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959410/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @Vladimir, если сделаете обещанное, ответ остаьте, пожалуйста, под [«исходным» вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/959410/178576).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, хорошо, я понял.